# Error Creating New Projects after installing Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've installed eclipse but when I created a new project, it generates the following errors:

```
workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:129: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:130: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
```

All of them in file *theme_base.xml.*

This is the first time I've had an error installing eclipse. Could it be something related to the graphics card?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reload installer, or just use Android Studio :)

Comment: i reload installer , and its fine

Answer (score 0):

This is likely related to the [`v7 AppCompat Library`](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html), as styles in `themes.xml` that have `Theme.AppCompat.*` parents use (as an example)

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
```

which is only applicable to API levels `21` and greater.

As I haven't used Eclipse in almost a year now I couldn't say how to resolve the issue in detail - I would definitely recommend using Android Studio though, as I now believe Google no longer supports Android Tools for Eclipse at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set target sdk of your project to maximum available (now it is 23). This will cause scanning for folders like v21 in appcompat v7 project. And yes, it's much better to switch to android studio now. At least it's maintained